# how to force node to synchronously log to console

Tags: node.js

I have some node.js code like that

```
console.log("diagnostic information");
nasty_stuff_fails_now();
```

Since console.log is asynchronously executed but "nasty_stuff_fails_now()" fails before the next tick of the event loop I never see the diagnostic information. How can I push the output to the console before nasty_stuff_fails_now() gets executed? Ideally I would like to synchronously push to the console. The performance penalty is acceptable during debugging.

Comment: you can also use `try...catch()` for error debugging/handling

Comment: which node.js version are you using?

Comment: node -v -->
v0.10.31

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it makes more sense, both semantically and for logic-wise, for you to use a try catch.

```
try {
  nasty_stuff_fails_now();
} catch( exception ) {
  //log diagnostic for failure
}
```

The console.log is atomic, so it should be printing everything before running the code that fails. If you are having a custom log function, that actually does async things. Then I would suggest you to return a promise.

```
logMyAsyncStuff().then( nasty_stuff_fails_now() );
```